# Why am I getting the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined at HTMLLIElement."?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Simple Todo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="source.css">
    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"
  integrity="sha256-iT6Q9iMJYuQiMWNd9lDyBUStIq/8PuOW33aOqmvFpqI="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
        <h2>TO-DO LIST</h2>
        <button id="slide">here!</button>
        <div>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Add New Todo">
        </div>
        <ul>
            <li>Buy Robes<button>Delete</button></li>
            <li>Go shopping<button>Delete</button></li>
            <li>Buy noodles<button>Delete</button></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="source.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is html file.

```
var li=document.querySelectorAll("ul li");
var btn=document.querySelectorAll("li button");
for(i=0;i<li.length;i++){
    li[i].addEventListener("mouseover",function(){
        btn[i].style.display="block";
    });
}
```

This is js linked to it.

I've set the buttons to display:none;in the css.
But when I am hovering over the li it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) in the for loop which declares a block scope local variable. You are trying to set `display="block"` to already visible elements. First set `display: none` to those elements using CSS:

```js
var li = document.querySelectorAll("ul li");
var btn = document.querySelectorAll("li button");
for(let i=0;i<li.length;i++){
  li[i].addEventListener("mouseover",function(){
      btn[i].style.display="block";
  });
}
```

```css
li > button{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h2>TO-DO LIST</h2>
  <button id="slide">here!</button>
  <div>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Add New Todo">
  </div>
  <ul>
      <li>Buy Robes<button>Delete</button></li>
      <li>Go shopping<button>Delete</button></li>
      <li>Buy noodles<button>Delete</button></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not the answer I am looking for. Actually I want the buttons to appear when I hover over the li associated with it. Obviously the 'this' keyword will select the whole li element but I want to select the button inside the li.

Comment: Hey @Mamum that solved the problem. But still I want a deeper understanding of let. I read a lot on other threads on how let is different than var. I got to learn that let has access only inside the block in which it is declared while var has all over access. But I am not sure how that solves the problem. var can also be accessed from anywhere inside the declared block then why can't it be accessed from the anonymous function?

Comment: @AjayKudva, if you declare with `var` the function which uses `i` in a later time, the value of `i` becomes `3` but if you use `let` because of its block-scope nature it preserves the actual value. You can play little bit with `console.log(i)` inside the function to check the differences individually....

Comment: My god. I've been learning Js for 15 days now and now I think I understood how var works. Correct me if I am wrong. The for loop does it's duty of adding event listeners to the li but it doesn't call the function. The function is only called when the click is performed. Hence when user clicks, the for loop has already looped through and i=3 now in my case button[3] doesn't exist hence the error. Whereas the let gives access to the inner ones as it creates different variables and preserves it in the scope. Am I right?

Comment: @AjayKudva, yes.....you are....